# Optimization answering rest springboot/jhipster

Tags: spring, spring-boot, hibernate, jackson, jhipster

Strange thing happens. I use jhipster approach to call the rest service which getAll instances of an object. Debugging I see the object are full, that's the Foreign Key to other entities are populated.

For example the entity Car has a Firm foreignkey pointing to the Firm producing the Car. So I see in:

```
return ResponseEntity.ok().headers(headers).body(page.getContent());
```

page.getContent() has an array of 3 cars of the Firm 1, 52, 1 (so I see the car1.getFirm().getDescription()==> "XXX", "YYY", "XXX"). It's all ok. But when I see the json arriving to my browser I see "XXX", "YYY", null. Extending, I see nothing about a Firm allready "used" in other response record of the same request.

Any idea about why this happens?

P.S. Here the code of rest service where I see in System.out the correct descriptions:

```
@GetMapping("/cars")
public ResponseEntity<List<Car>> getAllCars(CarCriteria criteria, Pageable pageable) {
    log.debug("REST request to get Cars by criteria: {}", criteria);
    Page<Car> page = carQueryService.findByCriteria(criteria, pageable);
System.out.println("---------------------------------------------");
for (Car car:page.getContent()) {
    System.out.println(car.getIdFirm().getDescription());
}
System.out.println("---------------------------------------------");
    HttpHeaders headers = PaginationUtil.generatePaginationHttpHeaders(ServletUriComponentsBuilder.fromCurrentRequest(), page);
    return ResponseEntity.ok().headers(headers).body(page.getContent());
}
```

Comment: can you post all of the code of that method?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the relationships are Hibernate lazy-loaded, when you print them in console or under debugger, you load them and they are non null. By setting `show_sql` to true, you should see the additional select statement being executed. Depending on which JSON annotations are used for your entities, Jackson will not serialize them.

Comment: Right. I solved frontend side. When answer of the rest arrive, I implement a little cache saving and retrieving the "used" things. In this manner I can put the correct entity not present in the answer.

Comment: Personally I think that solving it in frontend side often requires more work because you may have to handle several Observable with potential errors and also you may have to handle transactions when updating this object graph. This is usually when you realize that CRUD approach of JHipster is only the start of your project and you should consider DDD aggregates for your domain models :)